# Unable to run hadoop commands

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop on single node. While executing `hadoop fs -ls` i'm getting below:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Comment: This is just a warning, should not stop you from running the commands!

Comment: @franklinsijo When I run command hadoop fs -ls
It says '.' is not a directory.
Do I need to do some configurations? Please help.

Comment: You can try some more commands or run jobs and if you get any specific error then you can paste that here. As @franjlinsijo said this warning will do no harm.

Comment: @Sachit Murarka you are getting this because you are not specifying any directory and default it's taking as '.'

Answer (score 1):

As @franklinsijo said, it is just a warning, it won't affect your activities.

Coming to your `hadoop fs -ls It says '.' is not a directory`

If you execute `hadoop fs -ls`, it means `hadoop fs -ls /user/your_user_id`. It will show files from your home dir. So If you put any files in your home, then only it will list the files.

So try by giving the path like `hadoop fs -ls /` or `hadoop fs -ls /user/`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to list the directory. You can try with
 "hadoop fs - ls /"

Or try creating one hadoop fs -mkdir /test